# How to add class after particular field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have below html.

```
<input class="form-control dropify" name="photo" type="file">

<button type="button" class="dropify-clear">Remove</button>
```

now i have to add `deletephoto` class name with `dropify-clear` using above input name `name="photo"`. like this:

```
<button type="button" class="dropify-clear deletephoto">Remove</button>
```

Comment: $('.dropify-clear').addClass('deletephoto');

Comment: It's unclear when you want to apply the `deletephoto`class. Is it when focusing th `type="file"` input or when?

Comment: basically you need to use addClass attritube

Answer (score 3):

With jquery you can use [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/).

The below code will select a button with class `dropify-clear` which is next to input with name photo and will add a class using jquery `addClass`

```js
$("input[name='photo']").next("button.dropify-clear").addClass('deletephoto')
```

```css
.deletephoto {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control dropify" name="photo" type="file">
<button type="button" class="dropify-clear">Remove</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without jquery you can do like this:

```js
const removeBtn = document.querySelector(".dropify-clear");
removeBtn.classList.add("deletephoto");
```

```css
.deletephoto {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control dropify" name="photo" type="file">

<button type="button" class="dropify-clear">Remove</button>
```